# Dilate/erode - anchor point in matrix kernel topleft vs. middle

Tags: opencv, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

I have one function that does dilate/erode function by assuming that anchor point is topleft or first element of matrix.

[**1** 1 1]

[1 1 1]

[1 1 1]

I have other function that does dilate/erode function by assuming that anchor point is middle point of matrix.

[1 1 1]

[1 **1** 1]

[1 1 1]

Is there any way after dilate/erode operation to make first output matrix like the output from second one, i.e. shift image somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first case, the maximum element (dilation, or minimum element in erosion) within each 3*3 mask is set to the position `[-1,-1]`, while in the second case it is set to `[0,0]`. So if you are not considering the boundary effect, you will have

```
I1[0:n-1,0:m-1] == I2[1:n-2,1:m-2]
```

where `[n,m]` is the size of original image `I`, `I1` and `I2` are the morphological operations on `I` with the all ones kernel of topleft anchor point and middle anchor point, respectively.

You can compare the boundary values with similar analysis or just test the result directly with `dilate` and `erode`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the anchor point should be set to [0,0], in the second case should be set in the center, which is [1,1]. If you use [-1,-1] as anchor point, it will default to the center of the mask, useful for example when testing different kernel sizes. (see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#dilate)

For the rest you can check the tutorial:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html

Regarding your specific question, 
apart for situations at boundaries, you can get a submatrix of your output matrix (using the operator parenthesis from cv::Mat) in which the coordinates will be as you need.